# R Programming Calculate Rows Average

Tags: r, math, average, mean

How to use R to calculate row mean ?

Sample data:

[image]

```
f<- data.frame(
  name=c("apple","orange","banana"),
  day1sales=c(2,5,4),
  day1sales=c(2,8,6),
  day1sales=c(2,15,24),
  day1sales=c(22,51,13),
  day1sales=c(5,8,7)
)
```

Expected Results :

[image]

Subsequently the table will add more column for example the expected results is only until AverageSales `day1sales.4`. After running more data, it will add on to `day1sales.6` and so on. So how can I count the average for all the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `rowMeans`

```
> rowMeans(f[-1])
## [1]  6.6 17.4 10.8
```

You can also add another column to of means to the data set

```
> f$AvgSales <- rowMeans(f[-1])
> f
##     name day1sales day1sales.1 day1sales.2 day1sales.3 day1sales.4 AvgSales
## 1  apple         2           2           2          22           5      6.6
## 2 orange         5           8          15          51           8     17.4
## 3 banana         4           6          24          13           7     10.8
```

Comment: `f[-1]` might be more succinct than `f[2:length(f)]`

Comment: I succinct so too.  Changed.

Answer (score 2):

`rowMeans` is the simplest way. Also the function `apply` will `apply` a function along the rows or columns of a data frame. In this case you want to apply the mean function to the rows:

```
f$AverageSales <- apply(f[, 2:length(f)], 1, mean)
```

(changed 6 to `length(f)` since you say you may add more columns).

will add an `AverageSales` column to the dataframe `f` with the value that you want

```
> f

##    name day1sales day1sales.1 day1sales.2 day1sales.3 day1sales.4 means
##1  apple         2           2           2          22           5   6.6
##2 orange         5           8          15          51           8  17.4
##3 banana         4           6          24          13           7  10.8
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ?? Of course it provides an answer to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve it. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @Wulworine - I have no idea what you are on about. The answer as it stood solved the issue clearly. It did not have a long description but that is not unusual for the R tag, where the code can be run very quickly to show the result.